# How do I get Parker sector to 100% support in Red Faction: Guerrilla?

Tags: red-faction-guerrilla

I have Parker liberated and everything in it completed. I also drove through it for quite some time after that (only in the north part/can't figure out how to get to the south (?)) but no new events came up. It's currently at 84 % morale level (public support). How can I raise this number?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't think it was possible, but it piqued my interest so I had a rummage:

The only lead I can find on raising morale in liberated sectors is destroying (now empty) EDF buildings. Apparently is awards morale instead of reducing EDF control, post-liberation.